# TSQL aggregate functions to populate temp tables

Tags: function, t-sql, aggregate, temp-tables

I want to run a T-SQL script where I create a temp table that will be aggregated by a certain field of another table, call it table X. The remaining fields of this temp table will be populated by performing aggregate functions on the fields of table X. Then I would like to do a MERGE / WHEN MATCHED with my temp table on a different table (call it table Y) after I have populated the temp table.

How do I create this temp table and populate it with aggregate functions? (I have already coded the MERGE part of the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create a temp table you will can do the following:

```
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    col1 int
)
```

then you will write an `INSERT INTO`

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT col1, sum(col2)
FROM yourTable
```

Once you have created your temp table you can use it in your store procedure.

Answer (score 0):

What bluefeet posted, or:

```
with rsAggregated as
(
    select id, sum(x)
    from tableX
    group by id
)
merge...
```

Or, not seeing your merge statement, just

```
merge tableY using 
(
    select id, sum(x)
    from tableX
    group by id
) rsAggregated 
on rsAggregated.id = tableY.id
when matched
  ...
when not matched
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing with one SELECT statement

```
SELECT col1 AS ID, sum(col2) AS col1 INTO #temp FROM yourTable
```